# ModalDialog form doesn't work well

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have an application page. I want to click a button to pop out a dialog that is in the another application page. The dialog shows up and vanished in the air quickly. Of cource it didn't display the correct context of the page. I am using SharePoint 2010 and Visual Studio 2010. I used master page as well. Thanks.

```
<asp:Content ID="PageHead" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
<link href="../Stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink runat="server" Name="sp.js" OnDemand="true" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
 </asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Main" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="nav">
        <asp:Button ID="Edit" runat="server" Text="Edit" OnClientClick="javascript:Edit_Click()">

        </asp:Button> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function Edit_Click() {
                              SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js");
                              var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();

                              options.title = "My Dialog Title";
                              options.width = 400;
                              options.height = 600;
                              options.url = "/_layouts/Admin/test.aspx";
                              SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);

                        };


            </script>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the dialog shows up and then disappers is because your asp:Button performs a postback.

Try using

```
<asp:Button ID="Edit" runat="server" Text="Edit" OnClientClick="javascript:Edit_Click(); return false;" />
```

to prevent the postback.

Comment: There is no "return" attribute in button control.

Comment: `return false` is not an attribute, it's part of `OnClientClick` value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this bro.(..)

```
function Edit_Click() {
     $("#app_setup_wizard_container").dialog({
        autoOpen:false,
        height: 'auto',
        width: 'auto',
        resize:false,
        modal: true,
        position: [1230,220],
        url = "/_layouts/Admin/test.aspx";
        open: function(event, ui) {
            var $dialog  = $(event.target);
            var position = $dialog.dialog('option', 'position');
            $dialog.closest('.ui-dialog').css({
                left: position[0],
                top:  position[1]
            });
        },
        buttons: {
            Cancel: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
```